# Seamless switchover from 2G 3G WiFi

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi

Is there a way to handle a seamless handover for switching 2G ==> 3G ==> Wifi resp. other way around?

I see there is the `NetworkInfo`which returns null and I guess that Android first broadcast the switch of the LANs and then take a nap and reestablish the IP-address and the connections.  At least the sockets don't receive anything further.

Is there a way how to make a seamless handover/switchover possible?

Comment: Since you would be switching networks, and any open connections are to the IP address which is obviously changed in the switch, I don't see how there can be. You'd need an AS address to have seamless switching like that.

Comment: What do you mean with _AS address_?

Comment: @LeO, camelccc means you'd need to have an [ASN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_Number) and be multihomed by running [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP) on your phone, which is not a serious suggestion. Short of that, you'd either have to have a tunnel at all times from your phone to someplace that has a static IP address, or specific support in the applications for changing endpoint IP addresses.

Comment: Thx for the hints. Although I don't get it completetly why a switch from 2G to 3G is an internet-address change, cause the provider is more or less the same - from user point of view. Anyway thx for clarification...